# why sass compiler says undefined variable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i am using bootstrap **v5** using npm and using sass compiler to compile the scss. i want to customize ***.btn-primary*** .so in my dirctory *_button.sccs* file i made a *.btn-primary* class with icluding the **button-variant** mixin given from bootstrap.

but at compiling time it gives an error.

The code is below :

This is my **_custom.scss** file.

```
$yellow: #f8b534;
$small: 576px;
$medium: 768px;
$large: 992px;



//bootstrap imported
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here
// Copy
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap components as you like
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

Then my **_button.scss** file:

```
   @use '../custom' as *;

$btn-padding-y:               $input-btn-padding-y;
$btn-padding-x:               $input-btn-padding-x;
$btn-font-family:             $input-btn-font-family;
$btn-font-size:               $input-btn-font-size;
$btn-line-height:             $input-btn-line-height;
$btn-white-space:             null; // Set to `nowrap` to prevent text wrapping

$btn-padding-y-sm:            $input-btn-padding-y-sm;
$btn-padding-x-sm:            $input-btn-padding-x-sm;
$btn-font-size-sm:            $input-btn-font-size-sm;

$btn-padding-y-lg:            $input-btn-padding-y-lg;
$btn-padding-x-lg:            $input-btn-padding-x-lg;
$btn-font-size-lg:            $input-btn-font-size-lg;

$btn-border-width:            $input-btn-border-width;

$btn-font-weight:             $font-weight-normal;
$btn-box-shadow:              inset 0 1px 0 rgba($white, .15), 0 1px 1px rgba($black, .075);
$btn-focus-width:             $input-btn-focus-width;
$btn-focus-box-shadow:        $input-btn-focus-box-shadow;
$btn-disabled-opacity:        .65;
$btn-active-box-shadow:       inset 0 3px 5px rgba($black, .125);

$btn-link-color:              $link-color;
$btn-link-hover-color:        $link-hover-color;
$btn-link-disabled-color:     $gray-600;

// Allows for customizing button radius independently from global border radius
$btn-border-radius:           $border-radius;
$btn-border-radius-sm:        $border-radius-sm;
$btn-border-radius-lg:        $border-radius-lg;

$btn-transition:              color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;

$btn-hover-bg-shade-amount:       15%;
$btn-hover-bg-tint-amount:        15%;
$btn-hover-border-shade-amount:   20%;
$btn-hover-border-tint-amount:    10%;
$btn-active-bg-shade-amount:      20%;
$btn-active-bg-tint-amount:       20%;
$btn-active-border-shade-amount:  25%;
$btn-active-border-tint-amount:   10%;

.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant(
        $background,
        $border,
        $color: color-contrast($background),
        $hover-background:
            if(
                $color == $color-contrast-light,
                shade-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-shade-amount),
                tint-color($background, $btn-hover-bg-tint-amount)
            ),
        $hover-border:
            if(
                $color == $color-contrast-light,
                shade-color($border, $btn-hover-border-shade-amount),
                tint-color($border, $btn-hover-border-tint-amount)
            ),
        $hover-color: color-contrast($hover-background),
        $active-background:
            if(
                $color == $color-contrast-light,
                shade-color($background, $btn-active-bg-shade-amount),
                tint-color($background, $btn-active-bg-tint-amount)
            ),
        $active-border:
            if(
                $color == $color-contrast-light,
                shade-color($border, $btn-active-border-shade-amount),
                tint-color($border, $btn-active-border-tint-amount)
            ),
        $active-color: color-contrast($active-background),
        $disabled-background: $background,
        $disabled-border: $border,
        $disabled-color: color-contrast($disabled-background)
    )
};
```

But when compiling gives this **error** in below:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
   ╷
49 │         $background,
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  scss\components\_button.scss 49:3  @use
  scss\sections\_navbar.scss 2:1     @use
  scss\style.scss 6:1                root stylesheet
```

Comment: in  _button.scss   you used $background, but  $background   isn't define!
add  $background  in   _custom.scss   and set a value.